# Doctrine 2.0 in production

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

I would like to know if Doctrine 2 Beta 3 is stable enough to use for a production project? Do you have any success stories about it? What about api stability in general, and especially in recent betas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API has stabilized in the last betas, there have only been minor backwards compatibility breaks. Additionally we have now closed for new features and have no additional BC breaks planned. There are only bugs that will now be fixed for the stable release, which will hopefully happen around October.

I personally use Doctrine in a a production environment at work for about 4 month and haven't had any issues. Additionally we have had feedback from many companies that use Doctrine 2 in production.

If you want to use it, now is the time ;-)

Comment: Agreed. I've had Doctrine 2 in production since alpha. There were a few pain points early on, but it's been much smoother sailing since the betas. API is now very stable. I would check the JIRA on the project's page to see if there are any deal-breaker tickets open. Otherwise, go for it.